# Swift - How to pass dictionary of params to a function and send it on a get request?

Tags: swift, dictionary, parameters, request

I have a function that sends a request to a server. It works.

**Question:**
*I would like to pass parameters on the request. For example, client_id. Also, some other parameters can be added or no parameters at all.* **How can I do that?**

As noticed, client_id is hard-coded (for testing)

```
func makeRequest<T>(endpoint: String,
                completionHandler: @escaping (ApiContainer<T>?, Error?) -> ()) {
let token = DAKeychain.shared["token"]

guard let url = URL(string: endpoint+"?token="+token!+"&client_id=60") else {
    print("Error: cannot create URL")
    let error = BackendError.urlError(reason: "Could not create URL")
    completionHandler(nil, error)
    return
}
print(url)
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
let session = URLSession.shared

urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"

urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: {
    (data, response, error) in
    guard let responseData = data else {
        print("Error: did not receive data")
        completionHandler(nil, error)
        return
    }
    guard error == nil else {
        completionHandler(nil, error!)
        return
    }

    do {
        let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(ApiContainer<T>.self, from: responseData)
        completionHandler(response, nil)
    }
    catch {
        print("error trying to convert data to JSON2")
        print(error)
        completionHandler(nil, error)
    }
})
task.resume()
```

}

On a view controller I have this function that populates a tableview. I have to pass a param: client_id. The function will be called from other places on the application too. In addition, on the function, token is passed to the server to, via GET.

```
func getContacts() {
    makeRequest(endpoint: "http://blog.local:4711/api/contacts/all",
                completionHandler: { (container : ApiContainer<Contact>?, error : Error?) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("error calling POST on /getClients")
                        print(error)
                        return
                    }

                    self.tableArray = (container?.result)!

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
    } )
}
```

Comment: You are already passing parameters in the url. What are you really asking?

Comment: on the function call, i pass the url only. On the function I add token.. and i would like to add more params, for example, /clients/contacts/all. Where in this case, i have to pass the client_id.  
Sorry, I posted the wrong func. the correct is: getContacts. Post was edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build your URL according to what these parameters are. And the best way to build a URL is via the `URLComponents` struct:

```
func makeRequest<T>(endpoint: String,
                    parameters: [String: String],
                    completionHandler: @escaping (ApiContainer<T>?, Error?) -> ()) {

    guard var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: endpoint) else {
        print("Invalid endpoint")
        return
    }

    // Build an array containing the parameters the user specified
    var queryItems = parameters.map { key, value in URLQueryItem(name: key, value: value) }

    // Optional: Add default values for parameters that the user missed
    if !queryItems.contains(where: { $0.name == "token" }) {
        queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name: "token", value: "123"))
    }

    // Add these parameters to the URLComponents
    urlComponents.queryItems = queryItems

    // And here's your final URL
    guard let url = urlComponents.url else {
        print("Cannot construct URL")
        return
    }

    print(url)
    // ... rest of your function
}
```

Usage:

```
makeRequest(endpoint: "http://blog.local:4711/api/contacts/all", parameters: ["client_id": "42", "token": "xyz"], completionHandler: completionHandler)
// http://blog.local:4711/api/contacts/all?token=xyz&client_id=42
```

But if the user missed some required parameters, the function can add default values for them:

```
makeRequest(endpoint: "http://blog.local:4711/api/contacts/all", parameters: [:], completionHandler: completionHandler)
// http://blog.local:4711/api/contacts/all?token=123
```

Comment: it works... but the value can be String or Int. To 'fix' it, i had to add:  let client_id : String! = "\(client!.client_id!)"   ///  parameters: ["client_id": client_id]

Comment: It’s simpler if you keep that dictionary to string:string. Just convert all the values to a string before calling the function like what you did